# Оборот с «как» – сравнение или обстоятельство образа действия?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, обороты-с-как, сравнение

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, чем в предложении является оборот с «как»:

Пусть этот год придет(,) как сказка(,)
И радость в дом ваш принесет!

Мне кажется, что это обстоятельство, но, может, я ошибаюсь.
Как я понимаю, год не сравнивают со сказкой, а он должен принести с собой сказку. Правильно ли я понимаю, что запятые здесь не нужны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятые здесь действительно не нужны, а оборот является частью сложного сказуемого: ясно, что пожелание состоит не в том, чтобы новый год пришёл (он придёт в любом случае), а в том, чтобы он пришёл не абы как, а *как сказка*.

Answer (score 1):

Это предложение неправильно выстроено: у сказки нет какой-то характеристики, с которой она приходит. Можно было бы сказать: ‟Пусть этот год пройдет как сказка” — когда события складываются утопически благоприятно для вас.

Comment: Согласен, тоже это заметил. Ещё лучше: *как в сказке*.

Comment: Спасибо. Согласен, так лучше.

Comment: Смысл предложения именно в том, чтобы год пришел как сказка, а не прошел. То есть его наступление будет сказочным, волшебным.

Comment: @Олеся Тогда вам нужно такое предложение: ‟Пусть этот год наступает как в сказке”, а не ‟... придет как сказка”. В приходе сказки нет ничего магического, утопического и волшебного, так как она приходит как всё остальное. Магическим, утопическим, волшебным является её протекание.